# How can I code this to only work if the exact keyword "Taxi" or "Electric" is present. Electrical is causing problems for me. Thanks

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

// This script will be injected into all web pages

```
const bodyText = document.body.innerText.toLowerCase();

if (bodyText.includes("taxi") || bodyText.includes("electric")) {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "PINK";
}
```

Comment: Use a Regex with word boundary delimiters - see the duplicate

Comment: like this? // content.js

// Function to change the background color
function changeBackgroundColor() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'pink';
}

// Check if the page contains the keywords and change the background color
const keywords = ['taxi', 'electric'];
const textContent = document.body.textContent.toLowerCase();

if (keywords.some(keyword => new RegExp(`\\b${keyword}\\b`).test(textContent))) {
  changeBackgroundColor();
}